# Gerrit - Reload Plugins to incorporate changes

Tags: gerrit

I am developing some plugins for Gerrit 2.9 and usually copy the jar file into the Gerrit site's plugin folder.

However, I notice that it usually takes a while for Gerrit to pick up the changes made in the plugin jar file. One thing that automatically forces Gerrit to reload the plugins is to restart the server itself.

Next, I tried `ssh -p 29418 localhost gerrit plugin reload <plugin-name>`, however I get an error saying that **"Fatal: Remote plugin administration is disabled"**.

To solve the above message, I was able to find [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/3VRnSaHSum8) where the suggestion is to   **add missing configuration option: "plugins.allowRemoteAdmin = true"**. However I am not sure where to add this configuration option.

So any ideas on how to do a force reload of Plugins without having to restart the Gerrit server itself ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open `YOUR_GERRIT_DIR/etc/gerrit.config` file and add the following entry:

```
[plugins]
    allowRemoteAdmin = true
```

Save changes and restart your Gerrit instance. You will be able to reload / install plugins from remote host.